# Convert JsonNode into POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

This may seem a little unusual, but I am looking for an efficient way to transform/map a `JsonNode` into a `POJO`.

I store some of my Model's information in json files and I have to support a couple of version of my model.

What I do is load the json file in memory in a JsonNode, apply a couple of versioning strategies  to make it match the latest version of my Model.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(projPath));

    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(fileReader);

    //Upgrade our file in memory
    applyVersioningStrategy(rootNode);

    ProjectModel project = mapJsonNodeToProject(rootNode);
```

Unless there's a faster way to do it, I will probably end up simply manually applying the `JsonNodes` to my Model

Answer (score 398, accepted):

In Jackson 2.4, you can convert as follows:

```
MyClass newJsonNode = jsonObjectMapper.treeToValue(someJsonNode, MyClass.class);
```

where `jsonObjectMapper` is a Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

---

In older versions of Jackson, it would be

```
MyClass newJsonNode = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(someJsonNode, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no treeToValue(TreeNode n,TypeReference<T> type) variant like there is for readValue(). Bad news for anyone dealing with more complex types with generics :(

Comment: @Espinosa Per [jackson-databind#1294](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1294), you'll want something like (unfortunately more verbose) `jsonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonObjectMapper.treeAsTokens(someJsonNode), someTypeReference)`

Comment: For older version use: `objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, MyClass.class)`

Comment: You can also use this method in StdDeserializer: `p.codec.treeToValue`.

Comment: @icedtrees jsonObjectMapper is an instance of JsonObjectMapper or just the ObjectMapper

Comment: Instead of jsonObjectMapper.treeAsTokens(someJsonNode) one can also use  objectMapper.readerFor(MyClass::class).<MyClass>readValue(someJsonNode) with seemingly same amount of overhead, but with option to extract a reader for later use.

Answer (score 10):

This should do the trick:

```
mapper.readValue(fileReader, MyClass.class);
```

I say should because I'm using that with a `String`, not a `BufferedReader` but it should still work.

Here's my code:

```
String inputString = // I grab my string here
MySessionClass sessionObject;
try {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    sessionObject = objectMapper.readValue(inputString, MySessionClass.class);
```

Here's the official documentation for that call: [http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

You can also define a custom deserializer when you instantiate the `ObjectMapper`:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers

Edit:
I just remembered something else. If your object coming in has more properties than the `POJO` has and you just want to ignore the extras you'll want to set this:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Or you'll get an error that it can't find the property to set into.

Comment: I'll use a CustomDeserializers, it's gonna save me a lot of headaches!

I'll also be able to apply my versioning strategies in there with very little modifications. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax is now:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

mapper.disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

Comment: Good point @llambda! I haven't touched the ObjectMapper since version 1.7.9, it looks like my answer is out of date by a few versions. Definitely check what version of Jackson you're using.

Comment: @EricBarr, I am using Jackson v1.9.11 and the syntax in your answer is the correct one for that version. Perhaps they tried to change things and reverted them again in the newer versions

Answer (score 5):

If you're using org.codehaus.jackson, this has been possible since 1.6. You can convert a JsonNode to a POJO with `ObjectMapper#readValue`: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode, java.lang.Class)

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonParser jsonParser = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");
    JsonNode tree = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
    // Do stuff to the tree
    mapper.readValue(tree, Foo.class);
```

Comment: This methods seems to be missing in 2.4.4

Comment: See icedtrees' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28714523/60518) below, for a version 2 solution

Comment: The documentation is now at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Answer (score 4):

```
String jsonInput = "{ \"hi\": \"Assume this is the JSON\"} ";
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper =
    new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
MyClass myObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInput, MyClass.class);
```

If your JSON input in has more properties than your POJO has and you just want to ignore the extras in Jackson 2.4, you can configure your ObjectMapper as follows. **This syntax is different from older Jackson versions.** (If you use the wrong syntax, it will silently do nothing.)

```
mapper.disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNK‌​NOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a different way and can be used for an array of objects

```
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>() {
});
assert someJsonNode.isArray()
List<SomeClass> list = reader.readValue(someJsonNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `ObjectMapper` (if you're in a [custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915449/convert-jsonnode-to-pojo-inside-a-custom-deserializer/), for instance), you can use the `ObjectCodec` from the `JsonParser` parameter like this:

```java
jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(root.get("something"), MyClass.class)
```

This will give you the `something` object back according to existing serialization rules for `MyClass`.

Thanks to [@galcyurio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711695/convert-jsonnode-into-pojo#comment88151460_28714523) for the comment:

> You can also use this method in StdDeserializer: p.codec.treeToValue