# spring-webflux : How to Extract user defined object from Mono<T> or Flux<T> from the response without blocking?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, jsonnode

getUserDetails Method returns Mono of Type JsonNode. **But I Actually want to return a Mono<User.java> or Flux<User.java>.**  please help modifying getBulkUserInfo or getUserDetails to get the Mono<User.java> or Flux<User.java>

```
public Mono<JsonNode> getUser(BigInteger Id){
    return this.client.get()
            .uri("/URL/{Id}",Id)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
}

public Flux getBulkUsers(List<BigInteger> Ids){
    return Flux.fromIterable(Ids).flatMap(this::getUser);
}
```

But The json response from the Url is something like

```
{
"resultholder": {
            "totalResults": "1",
            "profiles": {
                "profileholder": {
                    "user": {
                        "country": "IND",
                        "zipCode": "560048",
                        "name":"Test"
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
}
```

I tried different ways but nothing worked subscribe() and
.doOnNext(resp -> resp.get("resultholder").get("profiles").get("profileholder").get("user"))

```
    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
.doOnNext(resp ->{return
 JSONUtils.deserialize(resp.get("resultholder").get("profiles").get("profileholder").get("user"), User.class)})
```

Comment: Did you look at these ?? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024999/convert-jsonnode-into-object/25026832 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711695/convert-jsonnode-into-pojo

Comment: Yes. I have already tried it. We have to use blocking to convert it to User.java using mapper.
can we return specific jsonnode without blocking?
'.retrieve().bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)' -Like do something with the response of Mono and then return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward and there is no need to block. Its just applying further mappings on the response. You can use the following code for your problem

```
 return webClient
            .get()
            .uri("profilesEndPoint/" + id)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
            .map(jsonNode ->
                    jsonNode.path("resultholder").path("profiles").path("profileholder").path("user")
            ).map(
                    userjsonNode -> mapper.convertValue(userjsonNode, User.class)
            );
```

Where mapper is jackson ObjectMapper

> private  final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

If you have any issues please refer to this code [here](https://github.com/harryalto/reactive-springwebflux/commit/b990f6b6026349cc96949d096f4404a934b58132) :