# Convert JsonNode into Java POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, unirest-java

I have this piece of code:

```
 HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://json.islandia.com/v1/martorell")
                .basicAuth("624823", "8f1addd21a09d6b95eaefa8d60p4c05")
                .field("day", "28")
                .asJson();

        Root newJsonNode = new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(response.getBody(), Root.class);
```

but I have this error: `Cannot resolve method 'treeToValue(JsonNode, Class<Root>)'`

Comment: Have you tried [`convertValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024999/convert-jsonnode-into-object) instead?

Comment: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Comment: I assume you are using Jackson ObjectMapper. I think you are confusing between Jackson JsonNode and com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode. Object mapper requires TreeNode, Jackson JsonNode implements TreeNode, com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode doesn't. Try converting the com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode to a Json string and then use ObjectMapper.readValue(string,class). Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [`ObjectMapper#treeToValue()`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/5e94cb1b29a5948737d86f5fe7eaeda318b74910/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L3390-L3408) does exist, check your import at the begginning of your file:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

If you do not see those imports, that could explain the error message.

Make sure that the [Jackson libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) are properly added to your project's classpath. You can add the following dependencies in your Maven's pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

> If I try using `convertValue` instead, I get:
>
> ```
> No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, > disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
> ```

So you are trying to serialize a `ByteArrayInputStream` object, which Jackson does not know how to serialize by default.

`HttpResponse.getBody()` might *not* be returning a JsonNode type: instead, it could be returning an InputStream which needs to be manually converted to JsonNode before you can utilize Jackson's conversion feature.

For instance:

```java
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = Unirest.post("https://json.islandia.com/v1/martorell")
                .basicAuth("624823", "8f1addd21a09d6b95eaefa8d60p4c05")
                .field("day", "28")
                .asObject(InputStream.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
Root newJsonNode = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, Root.class);
```

Here, the body of the HTTP response, which is an InputStream, is first converted to a JsonNode object using ObjectMapper.`readTree()`. *Then*, the JsonNode is converted to a Root object using `ObjectMapper.treeToValue()`. The Root class should be a POJO that matches the structure of the JSON you are working with. If it does not, you might run into more errors.