# Convert JsonNode to POJO inside a custom StdDeserializer, when ObjectMapper is not available

Tags: java, json, jackson

What I am trying to achieve is convert a `JsonNode` to a POJO (i.e. deserialize it) inside a custom deserializer.

Most other answers, like [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711695/convert-jsonnode-into-pojo), suggest using `ObjectMapper`, but the `deserialize` method specifically does not have the object mapper, so the solutions do not work. This question is therefore not a duplicate.

Here is my custom deserializer:

```java
class AccountDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Input> {
    public AccountDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AccountDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Account deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode root = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        User user = root.get("user").????;

        // other statements

        Account acc = new Account(user);
        return acc;
    }
}
```

(`User` is a simple class)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Mark, you closed this a couple of years ago as a dupe of the linked question, but this one specifically concerns how to do the conversion *without* an ObjectMapper (because it's not available). The other question might be for the more general case, but I'd never use this method if I *did* have the ObjectMapper, so it wouldn't be a very suitable answer for the other question. Similarly, I'd come here, not to the other question, if I was in a Deserializer.

Comment: That's why I think they're different questions. And this question also doesn't have an answer over there; just a comment.

Comment: I came across this question, and I agree, I don't think it's a duplicate. I've edited and requested it be re-opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `ObjectCodec` in `JsonParser` like this:

```
jp.getCodec().treeToValue(root.get("user"), User.class)
```

This will give you your `User` object back according to any other existing serialization rules.

Thanks to @galcyurio for the comment in [Convert JsonNode into POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711695/convert-jsonnode-into-pojo):

> You can also use this method in StdDeserializer: p.codec.treeToValue

Comment: thanks for answering an old but unanswered question!