# Jackson: parse json to Map<String, Object> for given Map<String, Class<?>>

Tags: java, jackson

I'm given a configured jackson's `ObjectMapper` instance with some modules, deserializers and configurations applied.

Also I have an "flat" json, meaning either no inner nodes, or `ObjectMapper` is able to parse that inner nodes to an single object.

I want to parse given json to `Map<String, Object>` (property name - deserialized object). Expected classes for each json property name are known, so I could pass them as `Map<String, Class<?>>`. How could I archive that target?

It's like parsing with `jackson.reader().fotType(Pojo.class).readValue()` to pojo and then collecting pojo fields with reflection. But I want to avoid extracting pojo's class, avoid using reflection and get in resulting Map only present in json properties.

Answer (score 0):

Solution inspired by [Convert JsonNode into POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711695/convert-jsonnode-into-pojo) :

1. Parse json to tree
2. Convert tree subnodes to expected java objects via treeToValue

Snippet:

```
public Map<String, Object> decode(String json, Map<String, Class<?>> propertyClasses) throws JsonProcessingException {
  final HashMap<String, Object> parsedFields = new HashMap<>();
  final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> jsonNodes = jacksonReader.readTree(json).fields();
  while (jsonNodes.hasNext()) {
    final Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> jsonEntry = jsonNodes.next();
    final String propertyName = jsonEntry.getKey();
    final Class<?> propertyClass = propertyClasses.get(propertyName);
    final Object parsedField = jacksonReader.treeToValue(jsonEntry.getValue(), propertyClass);
    parsedFields.put(propertyName, parsedField);
  }
  return parsedFields;
}
```